# Django connecting many products to one user

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many, one-to-many

I'm already a little tired of trying to connect the user profile to the articles he chose from the tables.
Namely, if user_1 chooses product_1 and product_2 and user_2 chooses product_1 and product_3, then both users will have assigned to their profiles product_1,2,3,1.
How can I solve this I have already tried the relationship "ManyToMany, ForeignKey and OnetoOne", looking for something like OneToMany connection.

Models:

```
class UserProd(models.Model):   
#prod = models.OneToOneField(Products, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
prod = models.ForeignKey(Products, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
date = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=True)  
diet_quantity = models.IntegerField(default=100)
unique_number = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Diet(models.Model):   
profile_user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True) 
date = models.TimeField(auto_now=True)
diet_prod = models.ManyToManyField(UserProd)
#diet_prod = models.OneToOneField(UserProd, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

and my views function:

```
@login_required
def add_prod_to_diet(request, pk):
user_profile = Profile.objects.get(user = request.user)         
unique_number = user_profile.pk
product = Products.objects.filter(pk = pk).first()
user_product, prod_created = UserProd.objects.get_or_create(prod=product, unique_number=unique_number)
if not prod_created:        
    user_product.diet_quantity += product.quantity      
    user_product.save()
else:
    user_product.diet_quantity=product.quantity
    user_product.save()
user_diet, diet_created = Diet.objects.get_or_create(profile_user=user_profile)
if unique_number == request.user.pk:
    user_diet.diet_prod.add(user_product)
    if diet_created:
        user_diet.unique_number = unique_number         
        user_diet.save()
    messages.info(request, f"Product {product} has been added to your diet plan.")
return HttpResponse(status=204)
```

Comment: You should use many-to-many relationship in this case. Not one to many. You have multiple products assigned to an user and then multiple users using the same product.

Comment: But in ManyToMany fields i'm getting connected all prods with all profiles despite the if statement i'm putting in func

Comment: No time to find your bug. But sometimes it's best to explicitly define a UserProductConnection with a foreign key to a user and a foreign key to a product, which is what Django many-to-many does implicitly. The advantage is that you can add information to the connection, such as chosen_on or favorite, and explicitly query connections.

Comment: @Piotr read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships), then all the rest of the documentation on  m2m relationships.